# How can I make my HTML canvas eraser replace only a specific color?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an eraser:

```js
this.ctx.globalCompositionOperation = "destination-out";
// ...
this.ctx.strokeStyle = item.c; // color
this.ctx.lineWidth = item.r;   // radius
this.ctx.beginPath();

let state = this.strokeState(item, i, prevItem);
if (state == "STROKE_ACTIVE") {
    this.ctx.moveTo(prevItem.x, prevItem.y);
} else if (state == "STROKE_BEGIN") {
    this.ctx.moveTo(item.x, item.y);
}

this.ctx.lineTo(item.x, item.y);
this.ctx.stroke();
this.ctx.closePath();
```

`item.c` always matches the actively selected color when the eraser is used. Right now, it just erases anything that's been drawn that intersects with the stroke. However, I'd like to add a mode where it will do that but *only* with the active color -- in other words, erase the active color and leave everything else alone (the purpose is for cleaning up sketched linework underneath the final drawing. Multiple layers are beyond my abilities at the moment.)

Is there a way to draw a transparent stroke while replacing only a specific color, maybe with a little bit of leeway for when erasing antialiased lines?

Here is an example of what I'd like to do.

[image]

Comment: This seems a lot harder to implement than layers, tbh.

Comment: See how the borders of the pink stroke fade to transparent? When the eraser passes there, these semi-transparent pixels go from showing the black background layer to the checkerboard one. This can only be done (correctly) with different layers. So go with layers, you'll save you a lot of time.